# How to convert SQL CONCAT To GRAPHQL query for hasura

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql, hasura

I would like to convert the following postgres query to graphql for hasura. How can I do it?

```
Select CONCAT(cast( "vendorId" as text),split_part("customerUserName",'+', 2)) as id,"vendorId","customerUserName"  from "VendorCustomertList"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Postgres VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html) and track that via Hasura. From there you have all the same capabilities as a table: changing GraphQL field names, relationships, permissions, etc.

http://localhost:9695/console/data/sql is where you can write custom SQL and have it be tracked as a migration.

[image]